# TypeScript definitions don't update on symlinked packages

Tags: symbolic-link, javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a project that uses [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#about) to manage dependencies in a mono repo application.

Essentially the folder structure looks like:

```
my-lerna-repo/
  package.json
  packages/
    package-1/
      package.json
    package-2/
      package.json
```

And these packages can use each other as dependencies, which lerna manages via symlinks.

The issue I have, is that when :

- I'm running package-1 and package-2 with `tsc --watch`,
- package-1 depends on something in package-2
- I make a change on package-2, it recompiles successfully.
- In VScode, when I'm looking at a file that that uses the package-2 dependency, it doesn't see the changes in the package-2 dependency, leading to red squiggles.

I can resolve this by ctrl+clicking into the dependency, and then navigating back - that resolves it.

However, that's a pain.

It looks like the [same issue was raised here on the TypeScript github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22656). However, there is no useful solution there.

Any suggestions for resolving this?

Comment: Do you have any test HelloWorld like project so that one can try?

Comment: Are you using Lerna with [Fixed/Locked mode](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#fixedlocked-mode-default) with a single version `lerna.json` file?

Comment: @Biswapriyo - here you go: https://github.com/dwjohnston/lerna-symlinks-example